# Inserting a constant/variable along with XML in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-openxml

I'm sure this has been answered before but I can't find the right nomenclature to find the answer.

Basically, I have a very simple table with 2 columns, both of data type int

Now, I'm trying to insert n records into the table with one of the columns being provided through an XML as so:

```
<Data> 
    <DepartmentID>{x}</DepartmentID>
</Data>
```

along with the constant value `@ProcedureID` is being passed along as a variable to the stored procedure.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @Handle OUTPUT, @Tags

INSERT INTO Accounting.DepartmentProcedure
(ProcedureID,DepartmentID)
SELECT @ProcedureID,DepartmentID
FROM OPENXML(@Handle,'/Data/DepartmentID',2) WITH (DepartmentID int)
```

The above parses fine, but running it gives me the following error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DepartmentID', table 'RCH.Accounting.DepartmentProcedure'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to deal with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the built-in XQuery functionality in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Data> 
    <DepartmentID>{x}</DepartmentID>
</Data>'

INSERT INTO 
    dbo.Accounting.DepartmentProcedure(ProcedureID, DepartmentID)

    SELECT 
        @ProcedureID,
        @input.value('(/Data/DepartmentID)[1]', 'int')
```

This inserts the value of `<DepartmentID>` extracted from the XML into the `DepartmentID` column.

Go here to read more about the [XQuery support in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19491) or read the [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005 on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Kudos man, can you suggest any references for the built in XQuery functionality?

Comment: @MustafaIsmailMustafa: I have two links in my answer- those are good starting points. Otherwise: search for "XQuery" on MSDN - tons of material there